# Gmail mobile browser client doesn't render html style tag

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm trying to hide some specific things on mobile but Gmail mobile browser client doesn't render the style tag. It works perfectly with Gmail apps for Android and iOS, the problem is on mobile browser.

For my needs, I need to use a class to hide the element, so I can't use inline styles.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
      .hide-mobile {
        display: none !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="hide-mobile">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Mobile
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, by "Gmail mobile browser client", do you mean using Gmail webmail (www.gmail.com) on a phone (whether Android or iOS)?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate why you can't use inline styles? Obviously if this client is removing embedded styles, then you're stuck.

Comment: @Nathan yes, accessing Gmail on a phone through Chrome/Safari. Are inline styles the only solution for that?

Comment: `<style>` is not supported on Gmail mobile webmail: https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-style/ so yes

Comment: @Nathan about the other question, I can't use inline styles because I need to use media queries. What I'm trying to do is to show some things on desktop and hide some on mobile

Comment: Ah, so you can use inline styles. Please let the experts decide how to best do it :). If I don't get around to it, you may be able to run with the theory that you can design for this client first (hide it inline), then use a media query max-width 600 for mobiles, and a min-width 600 for desktops.

Comment: @Nathan actually, media queries can't be placed as inline style

Comment: That's right. Sorry I wasn't quite clear. Hide it inline. Then in `<style>` put those media queries

Comment: "Gmail doesn’t support the `<style>` tag and, thus, media queries are not supported by Gmail, as they can only arrive in this form. For sending an HTML email, you’ll want to stick with Mailchimp or another ESP." [source](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/hiding-content-in-both-desktop-and-web-email-clients/)